# Clearing stuck blob upload jobs

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I'm not sure how I got into this state, but whenever I try and upload a certain blob on my computer

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -File $fileName -Blob $fileName -force
```

I keep getting this error telling me a transfer operation is in progress:

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : A transfer operation with the same source and destination already exists.
At C:\_SOURCECODE\FooProject\Deployment\AzureBlobSync_tasks.ps1:46 char:17
+ ...             Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Fi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureStorageBlobContent], TransferException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TransferException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.SetAzureBlobContentCommand
```

I'd rather just cancel the transfer operation in progress and start over, but how would I do that?

Comment: Does this work now? we can use `Stop-AzureStorageBlobCopy` to stop the transfer task.

Comment: I was no longer having this issue, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. Could you please post your detailed solution to this issue as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.

Comment: Don't know. It just went away on its own.